# directory not created from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-server-2003, ii6

I have a MVC.NET site which takes a user uploaded file and saves it.
Part of my code creates a new directory.

```
try
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    log.ErrorException("CreateDirectory failed", e);
    return false;
}
```

This works fine locally. However when deployed to IIS6 WIN2003 VPS it does not do anything. No exception is logged and no directory is created. In the windows permissions I have given 'Network Service' and 'Everyone' modify access to the parent folder. Why is no directory being created.

I also have code to save the file  `hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);` which also is not working when deployed. I tried installing ProcessMonitor but it will not run

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the right directory? Try `Path.GetFullPath(path)`

Comment: How is `path` formed? perhaps you're using an absolute path in your local development machine that doesn't exist (or that you don't have permissions for) on the server

Comment: - Does your application have the right permissions to create folders (locally, you're likely in admin context). Are you sure there is no exception or is it the `log` function that itself fails (and doesn't throw an exception)?

Comment: Try log the variable `path` in the `try` clause and see if it matches your expectation.

Comment: I tried all of these things and still no luck. The Path is what I expect it to be.  My application does have full permissions. The log is functioning correctly. The website is setup with "write" permissions

Answer (score 0):

I could never figure out why this did not work.

So I instead I changed the account the Application Pool ran under from 'network service' to a custom account with elevated privileges.